# Using Twilio in Rails 4 - A 'To' phone number is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, model-view-controller, twilio

I am following a Twilio tutorial ([HERE](http://richardgmartin.me/web-development/integrate-twilio-texting-ruby-rails-application/)) to add voice and sms to my rails 4 and keep getting the same error...A 'To' phone number is required. I think I have a to number defined...no? I have included all the relevant code below. Thank you in advance. Would also like to note that client_phone is a column in the table...the client_phone is entered by the user and then the button is clicked to share it.

Controller:

```
def share_over_sms

   twilio_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
   twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
   twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]

   @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token

   @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
     :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
     :to => @client_phone,
     :body => "This is a test."
   )
end
```

Route:

```
get "share_over_sms"
```

View:

```
<%= link_to 'Share Text', share_over_sms_listing_collection_path(@listing_collection), class: "button btn-nklyn-dark btn-2x" %>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: _the `client_phone` is entered by the user and then the button is clicked to share it._ The `@client_phone` variable is undefined, where is come from, parameters or any other?

Comment: @Зелёный It is included in the listing_collection_params.

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart can you print the value of '@twilio_client', twilio_sid and twilio_token before the call?

Comment: I dont see the `listing_collection_params`, I only see an undefined variable `@client_phone` in the method body.

Comment: Where is `listing_collection_params` coming from?

Comment: @philnash It's in the strong params.

Comment: OK, can you try using `listing_collection_params["client_phone"]` instead of `@client_phone` in the `:to` parameter to the API call. One other thing, I recommend using just `@twilio.messages.create` as the `.sms.messages` endpoint in the API is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike, did you try Phil's suggestions from above? Using `listing_collection_‌​params["client_phone"‌​]` instead of `@client_phone` in the `:to` parameter and using `@twilio.messages.create`? The `.sms.messages` endpoint in the API is deprecated.

I would also suggest taking a peek at the production ready code samples from tutorials like [this one](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/server-notifications/ruby/rails) to compare the Rails setup.